# Assembly - Error: junk '40' after expression

Tags: c, assembly

I'm using an i686-elf-as gcc cross compiler and it's failing to compile an assembly file.

The file is used alongside grub to boot my own operating system but when i try defining any globals or enter the _irq part it spits out tons of errors which are mainly

```
boot.s:78: Error: no such instruction: `irq4'
boot.s:81: Error: junk `0' after expression
boot.s:82: Error: junk `36' after expression
```

How would I stop this from happening?

Below is the entire boot.s file

```
# Declare constants used for creating a multiboot header.
.set ALIGN,    1<<0             
.set MEMINFO,  1<<1             
.set FLAGS,    ALIGN | MEMINFO  
.set MAGIC,    0x1BADB002       
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
.align 4
.long MAGIC
.long FLAGS
.long CHECKSUM

.section .bootstrap_stack, "aw", @nobits
stack_bottom: 
.skip 16384 # 16 KiB
stack_top:

.section .text
.global _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
    movl $stack_top, %esp

    call kernel_main

    cli
    hlt
.Lhang:
    jmp .Lhang


.global _irq0
.global _irq1
.global _irq2
.global _irq3
.global _irq4
.global _irq5
.global _irq6
.global _irq7
.global _irq8
.global _irq9
.global _irq10
.global _irq11
.global _irq12
.global _irq13
.global _irq14
.global _irq15

_irq0:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 32
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq1:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 33
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq2:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 34
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq3:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 35
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq4:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 36
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq5:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 37
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq6:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 38
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq7:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 39
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq8:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 40
jmp irq_common_stub

_irq9:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 41
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq10:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 42
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq11:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 43
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq12:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 44
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq13:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 45
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq14:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 46
    jmp irq_common_stub

_irq15:
    cli
    push byte 0
    push byte 47
    jmp irq_common_stub

extern _irq_handler

irq_common_stub:
    pusha
    push %ds
    push %es
    push %fs
    push %gs

    mov %ax, 0x10
    mov %ds, %ax
    mov %es, %ax
    mov %fs, %ax
    mov %gs, %ax
    mov %eax, %esp

    push %eax
    mov %eax, _irq_handler
    call eax
    pop %eax

    pop %gs
    pop %fs
    pop %es
    pop %ds
    popa
    add %esp, 8
    iret

.size _start, . - _start
```

Comment: `push byte 0` looks like NASM syntax to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're mixing Intel and AT&T syntax assembly language. GNU `as` uses AT&T syntax traditionally. Intel syntax is that used by assemblers such as NASM, MASM, YASM, and historical assemblers designed for the x86 platform.

`movl $stack_top, %esp` is a perfectly valid example of AT&T syntax assembly language. `push byte 35` is a perfectly valid example of Intel syntax assembly language. The two syntaxes, however, are incompatible, and cannot be combined.

I recommend looking up an assembly language tutorial that uses `as` on Linux, and learning how to use assembly language in the first place before jumping into something as complex and headache-inducing as systems development. ;)

http://asm.sourceforge.net/ -- Perhaps this tutorial/resource site could be of use to you. Good luck!

Comment: Jumping into systems development *is* learning how to use assembly language.